# Why does eclipse fail to run a step in feature file?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, cucumber, bdd

I have a scenario outline like:

```
Scenario Outline: This is some scenario
When User logs in
Then Something should be displayed "<msg>"
Then User logs out
 Examples: 
|msg|
|hi |
```

Here, the last step "user logs out" does not run even though it has an actual method corresponding to it.

I have tried basic solutions like checking the plugin, libraries, eclipse etc.

What could be the reason?

Comment: is there code you have written?

Comment: Please share the step definition you expect to be executed. As well as the runner and your file structure.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried running it with the option dryRun=true in the runner. Let it print out the methods for the step definitions and check if it still does not work.